# How should I troubleshoot "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos" in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am plotting histograms showing distributions of an angle `tau`. I used a random normal distribution as shown:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100000
tau = np.arccos(np.random.normal(-1, 1, N))
```

I got the error `"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos tau = np.arccos(np.random.normal(-1, 1, N))"`.

This did not pop up with a uniform distribution.
Why did this happened with the normal distribution?

Comment: arccos is defined on the range [-1, 1]. However, `np.random.normal()` can generate values outside this range.

Comment: `numpy.random.normal`'s first two parameters represent mean and standard deviation, not min and max. A normal distribution has no minimum or maximum.